# How to add text field dynamically with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi guys I'm using angular2 in my project and I'm trying to add an input text dymanically, and it works heres the code :

TS:

```
 initArray() {
  return  this._fb.group({  
            title: ['', Validators.required]
            })
}

addArray() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['myArray'];
    //this.myGroupName.push(newName);
    control.push(this.initArray());

}
```

HTML:

```
<div formArrayName="myArray">
    <div *ngFor="let myGroup of myForm.controls.myArray.controls; let i=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <span *ngIf="myForm.controls.myArray.controls.length > 1" (click)="removeDataKey(i)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" style="z-index:33;cursor: pointer">
            </span>
            <!--[formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]"-->
            <div [formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]">
                <div class="inner-addon left-addon ">
                    <i class="glyphicon  marker" style="border: 5px solid #FED141"></i>
                    <input type="text" style="width:50% !important" formControlName="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Exemple : Maarif, Grand Casablanca" name="Location" Googleplace (setAddress)="getAddressOnChange($event,LocationCtrl)">
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--[formGroupName]="myGroupName[i]"-->
        </div>
        <!--[formGroupName]="i" -->
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
<a (click)="addArray()" style="cursor: pointer">+ add text Field</a>
```

it gives me an error when i add a new text field, any suggestions please??

> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'myArray -> 1 ->

Comment: I think `Reactive forms` are a better choice than `Template-driven forms` when dynamically adding and removing form components at runtime

Comment: anyway the important is to make what you want

Comment: it gives me this error:Cannot find control with path: 'myArray -> 1 ->

Comment: post updated...

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not manupulate DOM with AngularJS
2. In controller create array of inputs

```js
$scope.inputs = [];
$scope.inputs.push({ id: 'input1', value: 'input1' });
$scope.inputs.push({ id: 'input2', value: 'input2' });
$scope.inputs.push({ id: 'input2', value: 'input2' });
```

```html
<input ng-repeat="input in inputs" ng-model="input.value">
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/AlexandrM/pen/OjwdoQ)

Comment: Thanks for answer.. but i4m using ANgular 2

Comment: @aqwaqwx In angular 2 you can use *ngFor. Approach similar.

Comment: please i updated the post.take a look to see what is my error